# Upload query suggestions into the GSA and activate immediately

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to upload query suggestions into the Google Search Appliance immediately.

I am using the load.py script available at [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/gsa-admin-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/load.py). I fire the script and it sends queries to the GSA. Following this, the output is as follows

> Tue May  6 09:05:22 2014: Thread-1: success: 0.0 secs query: /search?q=Hot+dogs&site=xxx&frontend=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend
>   Tue May  6 09:05:22 2014: Thread-2: success: 0.0 secs query: /search?q=Hot+dogs&site=xxx&frontend=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend
>   Tue May  6 09:05:22 2014: Thread-0: success: 0.0 secs query: /search?q=Hot+dogs&site=xxx&frontend=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend
>   Tue May  6 09:05:22 2014: Thread-1: success: 0.0 secs query: /search?q=Hot+dogs&site=xxx&frontend=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend
>   Tue May  6 09:05:22 2014: Thread-2: success: 0.0 secs query: /search?q=Hot+dogs&site=xxx&frontend=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend
>   Blockquote
>
> Load test report: 
>   Stats for Search:
>   Number of responses:
>       200:              1433
>       errors:           0   Latency:
>       median:           0.01 secs
>       maximum:          0.04 secs
>       std dev:          0.01 secs Stats for Overall:   Number of responses:
>       200:              1433
>       errors:           0   Latency:
>       median:           0.01 secs
>       maximum:          0.04 secs
>       std dev:          0.01 secs   Average QPS: 174.640644

However I can't see the query suggestions on the GSA. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your query is correct.  frontend should be replace by client.  The client parameter is how the GSA records searches.

Also, does the query that you are using return results?
Have you enabled it on your frontend: default_frontend

In 7.2 you can export the suggestions of a particular frontend.  You could examine those to see if the load test is successful.

Comment: So I have changed the parameter to client. I am still waiting for query suggestions to appear. When I export the query suggestions from the frontend It does not show the terms.

Comment: I am sorry but I should have directly answered you question.  You can not upload for load queries into suggest immediately.  Your approach may quick seed it, but it only takes a few queries and a few hours to seed it.  I would start using another front end with suggest enabled was BigMikeW suggested.  Once you see it there you'll be convinced that it dos work, and then use the url (with the correct client and collection parameter) to your load test.

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling show_suggest off then on again in your XSLT.